# How to update timestamp column moving date forward

Tags: mysql

what I am looking for is some help with a query.

I have a MySql field with unixtime in it representing a date in each of the next few dozen months.  I have to move the dates forward to the first day of the next month for each entry in the table.

The dates are all the 20th of each month, and so I want to move June 20 to July 1, July 20 to August 1, and so on.  I can't just add 11 days, because that wouldn't be the first day of the next month when considering months with 31 days and February.

I have been playing with ideas like this:

```
update table set column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(column + MONTH(column)+1,DAY(1)) where index_column = '1234'
```

but I am pretty sure that won't work.  I could use something like this to convert it, then try to convert it back:

```
update table set column = DATEFORMAT(column,'%Y-$c-%d %H:%i:%s') where index_column == '1234'
```

I still think there has to be a better way.  Frankly, I would update the few dozen manually, but I know this will come up frequently, and don't want to have to do it manually every time.

I prefer not to use code, but would instead like to just do it directly into MySql.  I hope there is someone out there that can help me figure this out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this Works:

```
update table set column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(column)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) where index_column = '1234'
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day

Comment: I thought this would work, but it's actually deleting the value altogether from the column, leaving it as a blank.  Since it is already a unix timestamp, so I changed it for another row to    update table set column = (LAST_DAY(column) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) where index_column = '1234'  and it came up the same way - no value anymore.

Comment: @WillSam what datatype is column field? LAST_DAY only works with dates, if is other datatype let me know to change the answer

Comment: It is a unix timestamp.  i Have been playing with   UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(column,'%Y-$c-%d %H:%i:%s')) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE index_column = '1234'    but I can't seem to get that to work either.  I get the same results, NULL feield.

Comment: I know that is a unix timestamp but the data type in the database is an int, varchar, date???

Comment: My apologies.  I save it as a varchar.

Comment: ok, i do a dummy table and test, this sql works for me: `UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(column)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

Comment: you can test each step, I mean, first do something like `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(column) FROM table` then `SELECT LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(column)) FROM table` and so on  to verify in what step you are getting the null

Comment: I'm not sure if there's better form, or something more efficient, but I used UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(column)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 12 HOUR) because I wanted it to be midday on that first day of the month.  This helped immensely,  thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe change `interval 1 day + interval 12 hour` to `interval 36 hour` but I don't think that makes difference. Glad to hear that you can fix the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Does [ADDDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) do it for you?  Or do you need something more?

Comment: No, because I need to go to the first of the month, which would result in a different value for ADDDATE depending on the months.